# Как с помощью selenium(java) найти push уведомление браузера и кликнуть по нему?

Tags: java, selenium

Как с помощью selenium(java) дождаться push уведомление браузера и когда оно появится кликнуть по нему ? Использую драйвер chrome и selenium 3. 
вот пример сообщения 
[image: пример push notification]

[image: пример push notification - 2]

Comment: вам точно нужно кликнуть по пушу? обычно  нотификации отключают в браузере при старте.

Comment: да, нужно кликнуть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то каждая нотификация может работать по-другому.

Решение 1. 
В консоли браузера добавляем JS код, который будет печатать нам URL нотификации. Мы собираем эти данные и сами решаем какой именно URL нам нужно.

```
// это JS
if ('Notification' in window) {
    messaging.onMessage(function(event) {
        console.log('url is: ', event.notification.click_action);
    });
}

// Это Java 
String js = "if ('Notification' in window) {\n" +
            "    messaging.onMessage(function(event) {\n" +
            "        console.log('url is: ', event.notification.click_action);\n" +
            "    });\n" +
            "}";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js);
```

Далее собираем логи с консоли, после появления нотификации и обрабатываем. 
Логи можно получить следующим образом:

```
getDriver().manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER).getAll();
```

Напоминаю, что каждый вызов возвращает только НОВЫЕ логи. 
Также нужно включить поддержку логов при старте браузера

```
LoggingPreferences logging = new LoggingPreferences();
logging.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logging);
```

Решение 2.

В консоли браузера добавляем JS код, который будет автоматически переходить по ссылке нотификации. Минус подхода в том, что если будет много нотификации за раз, то перейдет только по одному URL-у.

```
if ('Notification' in window) {
    messaging.onMessage(function(event) {
        console.log('url is: ', event.notification.click_action);
        window.location.href = event.notification.click_action;
    });
}
```

Полезные ссылки: 
[раз](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/), [два](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#event-onClicked)

протестировать можно [тут](https://peter-gribanov.github.io/serviceworker/)

- открыть сайт. Открыть DevTools.
- в консоль(вкладка Console) выполнить первый или второй JS скрипт.
- нажать кнопку SEND
- первый скрипт напечатает в консоле "url is: www...", второй скрипт дополнительно перейдет по этому URL

Comment: Пока ни один вариант не заработал. Что-то не правильно делаю видимо. Подскажите по первому варианту... Как получить логи в Java код ? Второй вариант можно использовать внутри ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(/*скрипт сверху*/); ?

Comment: @Adrenal1ne обновил вопрос. посмотрите

Comment: Становится всё понятнее )) Можно как-то внедрить скрипт в консоль программно из Java кода ? Или нужно просто посредством ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js); выполнить первый скрипт, чтобы он работал и снимал логи в браузере ?

Comment: @Adrenal1ne нужно выполнить через JavascriptExecutor после старта браузера или непосредственно перед появлением пуша